Fancyhdr place everything wrong in Tex file using input command
I wanted to use the Fancydhr package for my documents for the first time.
I have created a little LaTeX file wich have this structure:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}

\pagestyle{fancy} % Attiva il pacchetto Fancyhdr

\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.4pt}

\fancyfoot{}

\fancypagestyle{Default}{
    \fancyhead{}
    \fancyfoot{}
    \fancyhead[L]{Dispensa di Matematica}
    \fancyhead[R]{Quarto Anno}
    \fancyfoot[L]{4LC}
    \fancyfoot[R]{\thepage}
}

\pagestyle{Default}

\title{Dispensa di Matematica - Programma di Quarta}
\author{Lorenzo Lettieri}
\date{A.s 2024 / 2025}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\newpage

\renewcommand{\contentsname}{Indice}

\begin{multicols}{2}
\tableofcontents
\end{multicols}

\newpage

\newgeometry{margin = 1cm}

\input{Sections/Goniometria}

\end{document}

In the Goniometria.tex file I wrote simply this:
\section{Goniometria}
\noindent Ciao

Even if I think that everything I wrote is right, my document still look like this:


As you can see, headers and footers are misplaced.
What have I done wrong?

BTW: The example cannot work. At least \usepackage{geometry} and \usepackage{multicol} are missing. Please always test the code you are posting.

You are likely interested in the includeheadfoot option as part of your \newgeometry setting, since a 1cm margin is too small to contain the header/footer. Additionally, a change in the geometry requires a recalculation (see fancyhdr ignores \newgeometry).

\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{fancyhdr,multicol}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\fancypagestyle{Default}{
  \fancyhf{}
  \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.4pt}
  \fancyhead[L]{Dispensa di Matematica}
  \fancyhead[R]{Quarto Anno}
  \fancyfoot[L]{4LC}
  \fancyfoot[R]{\thepage}
}

\pagestyle{Default}

\begin{document}

\renewcommand{\contentsname}{Indice}

\begin{multicols}{2}
\tableofcontents
\end{multicols}

\newpage

\newgeometry{margin=1cm,includeheadfoot}
\fancyfootoffset{0pt}% <- recalculate \headwidth
\pagestyle{Default}% Reset the headers/footers under new geometry


\section{Goniometria}
\noindent \lipsum

\end{document}


Thank you so much, It worked
